# Error: expected primary-expression before char

Tags: c++

I have a problem in the `if` clause I guess the code is correct but I don't know why there is a problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;
   cout<<"Enter a Number and we will tell you the loop"<<endl;
   cin>>a;
   {
      if(a=char)
      {
         cout<<"Enter only Numbers"<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout<<"The value is: ";<<a<<endl;
      }

   }
   do
   {
      cout<<a<<endl;
      a++;
   } while(a<=10);
   cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It would be great..Thanks

Comment: No the code is not correct. That's why the if() statement is a problem. "if(a=char)" is not valid C, or C++.

Comment: I would highly recommend researching and learning about how to write simple c++ program, variable typing, and the difference between assignment and equality.

Comment: so how can i correct it I want that if **a** = character then the code should give an error.

Comment: The variable `a` will _always_ be an integer, never a character, because you declared it to be an integer (`int a`). Try looking up what error codes `cin` produces. It may just have a way for you to know that the read failed because a character was given when an integer was expected. (I'm not well versed with `cin`, so I can only guess that it has something like that.)

Comment: `a` will never be character. It's declared as an `int`, so `operator>>` will parse it as a number. If a non-number is entered, the `operator>>` conversion will fail, and `std::cin` will enter a failed state.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Thanks for the confirmation. I figured `cin` would do something like that.

Comment: Also, you have a semi-colon in the middle of the `cout` statement in the `else` clause. It's a different error, but it will cause problems too.

Comment: i don't want a to be a char i just want that if the user enters a char then the code will give the error instead of the output!!

Comment: ya but the semi colon is for inside double quotes so that shouldn't cause any problem!! @Kyle A

Comment: @sogyalsherpa Then you have a typo, because it is not inside the double quotes.

Comment: Thank You guys for the help...i solved the program with the help of my friend ill post the code for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check the type of a variable by trying to compare `a` and `char`.

`a` was declared an `int`, and will always be an `int`.
You don't need to check its type, you ***know*** what type it is.

If you truly want to accept any data, and then check to see if it can be converted to an `int`, then you need to accept a `string`, and try to parse that string:

```
int main()
{
    string a;

    cout << "Enter a Number and we will tell you the loop" << endl;
    cin >> a;  // Get a string from input

    int number;
    try
    {
        number = strtoi(a, 0, 10);  // Try to convert the string to an int
                                    // Throws an exception if it cannot be converted.
    }
    catch(const invalid_argument&)
    {
        // If the number could not be converted, catch the exception, and show an error message.
        cout << "Enter only Numbers" << endl;
        throw;
    }

    cout << "The value is: " << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no but I know 'a' is declared an 'int' but then im just using trying the program to say that **if** 'a' is equal to a character then the code should give an error.

Comment: Finish your own damn code.  I wrote out the important parts.

Comment: i know that i have done that i can finish my code myself i just thought you didn't see that..bro!

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, "a" will always be an int. cin.fail() in the below code can help you check for entry that is not a number and flag it.Hope this helps.

```
int a;
    cout << " Enter a number" <<endl;
    cin >> a;

        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cout <<"Error. enter a number " << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cin >> a;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is **always** an integer. Even if you enter a character, it'll be given the ASCII value of the character.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the question.

#include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a;

cout<<"Enter a Number and we will tell you the loop"<<endl;
cin >> a;

if(a) {
    cout<<"The value is: "<<a<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"Enter only Numbers"<<endl;
}

do{
    cout<<a<<endl;
    a++;
}while(a>=100);

cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
```

}